# How to set default values for missing environment variables in maven pom

Tags: maven, environment-variables, default-value, setter

### Is it possible to have maven provide default values for missing environment variables? If so, how?

---

## Context:

I have properties files with placeholders to environment variables, like this: `my.property=${env:ENVIRONMENT_PROPERTY}`

Running maven (edit: not like this `mvn ... -DENVIRONMENT_PROPERTY=some_value`) if the environment variable is set in the OS makes it resolve the property placeholder with the given value. But if the environment variable does not exist, the value is blank.

## Problem:

I would like the environment variables to have a default value. If the environment variable does not exist it should be given a default value that would be specified in the pom or some properties file or whatever.

## Important:

The property placeholders have to point to an **environment** variable.

Comment: First for what purposes are those env variables? Which make your build env dependent..?

Comment: We are in a transition to deploy with Docker, which uses environment variables. But for local development we are not quite there yet, and a regular maven build is more flexible there.

Comment: Hm..if you deploy with Docker than the build should produce all artifacts for all environments?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I used the felix fileinstall plugin (`org.apache.felix.fileinstall`)
This allows the following notation:

`${env:ENVIRONMENT_PROPERTY:-default value}`

This will take the value from the ENVIRONMENT_PROPERTY and if that is not set, it would take "default value".

---

EDIT:
If you want to take the default values from maven properties, you need to use the ${dollar} hack:

`${dollar}{env:ENVIRONMENT_PROPERTY:-${default.value}}`

where `dollar` is a maven property that is resolved to a dollar symbol (`<dollar>$</dollar>`) which turns into a delimiter when combined with the `{` bracket.

Comment: It doesn't work either. Show how do you use `org.apache.felix.fileinstall`. Because `${dollar}{env:ENVIRONMENT_PROPERTY:-${default.value}}` never have been existed.

Answer (score 10):

You might define a property with a default value.

```
<your_property default-value="Undefined">${env.environent_variable_name}</your_property>
```

That's it!
If you define `environent_variable_name` then `your_property` will be equal to it; otherwise, the `your_property` will be equal to `Undefined`.

Comment: I've managed to use this in a slightly different manner: I've set my own property to the default value and changed at runtime, if needed, with -Dyour_property=other_value

Answer (score 2):

The maven resources plugin is your friend. It should already run as part of your build. But it does not filter resources by default. You have to configure that:

```
  <resource>
     <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
     <filtering>true</filtering>
  </resource>
```

Then configure a filter:

```
<build>
   ...
   <filters>
      <filter>my-filter-values.properties</filter>
   </filters>
```

Put the default values you want into that file.
Given the precedence of properties in maven:

(1) command line (2) settings.xml (3) pom.xml (4) filters

The properties in your filter file can act as what you want to have as defaults.

For a proper explanation of filters, consult the official documentation: Filters under the maven-resources-plugin ! (It's [here](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/filter.html))

Comment: Thanks, the precedence of properties shared by you helped me. I had to use environment specific filter-values-${env}.properties. I also had to support normal build command *without* `-Denv=dev` filter for daily builds, as I used to do earlier. I ended up setting default value as a property in pom.xml itself. Only when I need other values, I supply it via command line.